# Bluetooth Headphones refuse to use A2DP High Quality

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, a2dp

Trying to use my bluetooth headphones with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 but they refuse to use A2DP High Fidelity Playback and instead always uses low quality HSP/HFP. No matter what I've tried it never sticks with A2DP.

Answer (score 0):

followed the instructions on this page:

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-i-got-my-bluetooth-headphones-to-work/410

then got into blueman using blueman-manager in the terminal, and used that to connect.

got my headphones working (finally) on 17.04.

good luck!